# Displaying Correct information on my webpage.

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data, thymeleaf

My question is **How can I use my getLabel, getX, getY from my NodeEntity class and display the results of my query on my web page instead of getting "org.neo4j.ogm.response.model".** I do not know if these get methods should be used within the controller or repository class in order to display the node information on the web page table.

```
@NodeEntity
public class Room {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Property(name = "label")
    private String label;

    @Property(name = "shape")
    private String shape;

    @Property(name = "colour")
    private String colour;

    @Property(name = "x")
    private String x;

    @Property(name = "y")
    private String y;


    @Relationship(type = "To")
    private Collection<Room> roomTo = new ArrayList<>();

    @Relationship(type = "Up")
    private Collection<Room> roomUp = new ArrayList<>();

    @Relationship(type = "Down")
    private Collection<Room> roomDown = new ArrayList<>();

    @JsonIgnoreProperties("room")
    @Relationship(type = "To", direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
    Collection<RelEnt> relEnts;

    public Room(){

    }
    public String getLabel(){
        return label;
    }

    public String getShape(){
        return shape;
    }

    public String getColour(){
        return colour;
    }

    public String getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public String getY() {
        return y;
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
public interface NavigatorRepository extends Neo4jRepository<Room, String>{

    @Query("match (r1: Room {label: {from}}), (r2: Room {label: {to}}), p = shortestPath((r1)-[*]-(r2)) unwind nodes(p) as room return room")
    Iterable<Map<String, Object>> getShortestRoute(@Param("from") String from, @Param("to") String to);
}
```

Service:

```
@Service
public class NavigatorService {

    @Autowired
    NavigatorRepository navigatorRepository;

    public Iterable<Map<String, Object>> shortestRoute(String from, String to){
        return navigatorRepository.getShortestRoute(from, to);
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class AunController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/AUN") //this will allow you to access web page with just http://localhost:8081/
    public String homePage(){
        return "AUN-Web"; //uses the static html file created for the web page
    }

    @Autowired
    NavigatorService navigatorService;

    @GetMapping(value = "/navigate")
    public String navigate(@RequestParam(name="from") String from, @RequestParam(name="to") String to, Model model) {
       Iterable<Map<String, Object>> route = navigatorService.shortestRoute(from, to);

        model.addAttribute("from", from)
                .addAttribute("route", route)
                .addAttribute("to", to);
        return "AUN-Results";
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/")
    public String error(){
        return "Error/404";
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
 <form action="/navigate" method="">
        <strong><label for="ifrom">Current Location:</label></strong> <br>

        <input id="ifrom" type="text" placeholder="MB" name="from"><br>

        <strong><label for="ito">Destination:</label></strong> <br>

        <input id="ito" type="text" placeholder="MB" name="to"><br>

        <p style="line-height: 30px; width: 300px;"></p>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="result">Search</button>

        <p style="line-height: 30px; width: 300px;"></p>
    </form>
</div>

<div align="center" class="container-fluid">

    <h5>Going from <span th:text="${from}">MB220</span> to <span th:text="${to}">MB265</span></h5>
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th>Label</th>
                <th>X</th>
                <th>Y</th>
            </tr>
            <tr th:each="route : ${route}">
                <td th:text="${route}">Mb220</td>

            </tr>
        </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your foreach var name to something like "routpoint" so it differs to the complete route.

Comment: sorry I don't quite understand what you meant by that, could you give me an example?

Comment: `<tr th:each="route : ${route}">
                <td th:text="${route}">Mb220</td>

            </tr>` 
there you wrote to read out of the var. route and write each element to the var route. I'm not sure if that works. Please change the var. name you are writing into to "routepoint".
`<tr th:each="routepoint : ${route}">
                <td th:text="${routepoint}">Mb220</td>

            </tr>`

Comment: unfortunately this change did not work as I am still getting the print out of org.neo4j.ogm.response.model on to my webpage. I feel that I must use getLabel() and the other get methods from my nodeEntity class in order to retrieve the room labels and X and Y coordinates.